# Is there a way to detect motion controls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, gamepad-api

Is there a way to detect motion controls from a JoyCon in vanilla JavaScript? If it's not possible, would I be able to use another API besides `Gamepad API`?

```
window.addEventListener("gamepadconnect", function(e) {
  //How would I detect motion controls?
});
```

Comment: Some examples on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API

Comment: I can't find anything about motion controls, just buttons and joysticks.

Answer (score 0):

[Gamepad Extensions](https://w3c.github.io/gamepad/extensions.html) describes motion inputs for gamepads, but it's not officially part of the specification and no browsers implement it for Switch controllers.

It's [possible](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuhQXXgDnCQ) to access Joy-Con motion inputs with WebHID.